# GWT move buttons with left key and right key

Tags: java, gwt, button

I have many buttons in a vertical panel i can move from each button with tab key but i can't move with keyboard up, down , right or left. What is the comand for enble this function ?thx

Comment: There's no simple command, I guess. You need to detect keystrokes and move the focus appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VerticalPanel panel =//;
panel.addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
    switch (event.getNativeKeyCode()) {
    case KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT:
      //...
    case KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT:
    }
  }
}, KeyUpEvent.getType());
```

Comment: i try this code final Button one = new Button("ONE");
  final Button two = new Button("two");
  VerticalPanel panel =new VerticalPanel();
    panel.addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        switch (event.getNativeKeyCode()) {
        case KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT:
         one.setFocus(true);
        case KeyCodes.KEY_RIGHT:
         two.setFocus(true);
        }
      }
    }, KeyUpEvent.getType());  BUT NOT RUN

Comment: Cool.

If it works for you, you should accept the answer. :)

Feel free to include anything else you discovered in case someone else comes across this post.